# Static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++, static, initialization, static-order-fiasco

In his "Thinking in C++" (Chapter 10) Eckel describes a technique that was pioneered by Jerry Schwarz to solve the fiasco. 
He says that if we want to initialize *x* to 100 and *y* to 200 and share them among all translation units, we create an Initializer.h that looks like this:

```
extern int x;
extern int y;
class Initializer {
   static int initCount;
   // if (initCount++ == 0) x = 100 & y = 200
   /* ... */
};
static Initializer init;
```

And in implementation file we have

```
#include "Initializer.h"
int x;
int y;
int Initializer::initCount;
```

and Eckel says that "static initialization (in implementation file) will force all these values to zero".

Let me consider the following case: the compiler processes the implementation file *after* some other file with that header included (it means that x and y have been already set to 100 and 200 in that other file). The compiler sees `int x`, so what will it do? Will it set x and y to zero eliminating initialization and all possible changes in previous files? But if it does, then `initCount` will also be set to zero, breaking down the whole technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But if it is true, and the compiler handles the implementation file after some another file, than it will set x and y to zero eliminating initialization and all possible changes in previous files?

I'm not sure what you mean by this. If `x` and `y` are defined in other files, then you have a linker clash and the program simply won't compile.

If `x`, `y` and most importantly `Initializer::initCount` are implemented in this way, there will be unique instances of them in the program; they are effectively global and will be initialized to `0` at program start, *before* any `Initializer` is constructed (due to inclusion of the header declaring a `static` instance of that class). Each construction of a `static Initializer` will first check whether any other `Initializer`s have been constructed due to the `if (initCount++ == 0)` etc.

The first `Initializer` ctor to run (still before entering `main`) will thus set all three values.

Comment: I might add that it's marginally safer to replace `initCount` with `bool done` and do `if (not done) { done = true; ... }`. But I'm probably one of the few people how would take the possibility of `INT_MAX` translation units into account.

Comment: I understand that, but I meant another aspect (see Mark B comment): after x was initialized (when the compiler mentioned "extern int x;" in some source file) and then assigned to 100 in that source file, compiler goes ahead, sees implementation file, doesn't assign x to anything (because initCount != 0), but then sees "int x;" and assignes x to 0, eliminating the fact that x i alsready 100.

Comment: The initCount is there for the case where you need to destroy the objects as well. Then the Initializer destructor would decrement the count until it reaches zero, and then delete or close whatever is needed.

Comment: @Bo Persson: in which case `size_t` would be the correct (and self-documenting) type to use.

Answer (score 3):

What is done in "Initializer" is assignment, not initialization (assuming valid syntax).

As such, it "solves" the static initialization order fiasco for your special case, *because there is no fiasco in the first place*. x and y are integers, they don't call each other at unpredictable times, and on top of that they live in the same translation unit too. The compiler will just initialize them proper. It's fine if you assign values in a defined order afterwards, but it's only more complex, not any better.

For the  static initialization order fiasco to appear, you would need a situation like: constructor of x needs the value of y (or the other way around) and they are in different translation units. Therefore, it's a 50:50 chance whether this works or not.

Now, the "Initializer" struct will correctly *assign* values in a defined order, but at that time, the *constructors* of x and y have already run, because you can't assign to what has not been constructed... so it would not avoid the problem at all, if it existed.

Construct on first use is the common way of dealing with this problem. There are different flavours (each with its own advantages and disadvantages) of that technique, such as for example:

```
x& get_x() { static x *xxx = new x(); return *xxx; }
```

Comment: skt: `x& get_x() { static int x; return x; }` does not leak (the leak occurs if you onload the DLL, instead of exiting the process), it's got a problem of static finalization fiasco though :/

Comment: Yes, this implementation leaks one instance of type x (thumbs up for spotting it). That is however "expected behaviour" of this implementation. Like I said, there are several solutions to the problem, each having its own advantages and disadvantages. An alternate well-known implementation returns a reference to a static local, this does not leak but calls destructors in a undefined way, which often is ok, but will be a problem if for example x::~x() calls y::~y(). If y has already been destroyed (50% chance), the program will crash at exit, every time, and nobody will know why.

Comment: The forementioned is explained here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.16

Comment: skt: I know the faq entry :) the issue with the leak is two-fold though, the memory leak itself is rarely an issue, but it also means that the destructor is never executed either, which can be a problem if, for example, this is a logger, in which case we want to flush on destruction. For full blown singletons, we would probably use `atexit` and perhaps some way to resurrect them (setting the pointer to 0 after destruction). It gets a bit more complicated, and there's the issue of synchronization among multiple threads...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean any possible use and initialization at static-init scope in other source files then you're absolutely correct: If the compiler decided to run this file's static initialization after that in other files then you'll undo that other work.

In many cases you can save yourself a tremendous amount of headaches by just not using globals/statics at all.

Answer (score 1):

The global x and y will be initialized to zero when the program is loaded, before any code was executed. When any Initializer is created, x and y are already initialized to zero. Things happen in that order:

1. Program is loaded
2. Global and static variables are zero initialized (x and y get their 0 values)
3. Global objects are constructed (the Initializer sets x and y to 100 and 200)

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare (at file scope, in a single translation unit):

```
int x = 100;
int y = 200;
```

x and y will be stored in the image's read/write section so they are initialised before *any* code in the process executes.  You don't need to worry about initialisation order for plain-old-data.