# Automatically create instance of inheritances

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, c++11, metaprogramming

I am programming in *c++11* and *boost* and i am trying to implement some kind of framework where someone just needs to inherit from  **class Base** and implement **method()**, which may depend on other inheritances. 
These inheritances should then be automatically created in the main function, without any modification by the programmer.

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void method() = 0;
}

class A : public Base
{
public:
   static int state = 0;

   void method()  //
   {
      //do something with B
      A::state = B::state * 3;
   }
}

class B : public Base
{
public:
   static int state = 0;

   void method() //
   {
      //do something with A
      B::state = A::state * 2;
   }
}

int main()
{

//Access to an Array containing ONE pointer to each Inheritance

vector<Base*> inheritancesOfBase;
inheritancesOfBase.push_back(new A); // <- should be done automatically 
inheritancesOfBase.push_back(new B); // <- should be done automatically 

//PSEUDOCODE
for_each(base* pInh in inheritancesOfBase)
{

    pInh->method();
    clones.push_back(pInh->clone());

}


return 0;
}
```

I think this should be doable with some fancy metaprogramming, but how?

EDIT: clarification

Comment: It's not clear what you really want - to create some As and Bs depending on something at runtime, or to create new types of classes at runtime (using compile time metaprogramming...?)

Comment: In the end i would like to have an array containing one instance (or pointer) of each inheritance.

Comment: I think i have found a solution to my problem [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410942/c-automatic-instantiation-of-derived-classes

Comment: cool. Feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your code will not compile as you are missing the defintion of the statics. You need to add `int A::state = 0` (or similar) to the code and the same for `B::state`.

Second, an automatic creation of A and B objects is not possible, as the compiler cannot know, what you intentions with the code are. Hence, you need at least to have some declaration of A and B objects in the main. E.g. how should the compiler know, that you need exactly one A and five B objects? So you must state your intention to the comiler:

```
int main(void)
{
    A myA;
    B myBArray[5];
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> myABCollection;
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't compile cos it has missing semi-colons after the classes

Answer (score 0):

So, we have something like

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void method() = 0;
};
```

(Don't forget the semicolons after the classes)
and lots of subclasses, not just the `A` and `B` shown.

We want `main` to do something like

```
for(Base & item : instances)
{
    item.method();
}
```

You could make a factory, that keeps track of what it creates in a `vector<shared_ptr<Base>>` and return the `instances` when asked.

That solves half the problem. If you want to find all classes that derives from `Base`, given C++ doesn't have reflection I can't see how you'd do that. You could piece something together using clang and generate some code that way. The [RecusiveASTVisitor](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) might help.

Comment: Thats exactly what i meant.

Comment: Basically what i wanted to avoid is that the programmer, who implements a new method, needs to propagate its existence somewhere else in the project... Maybe i am running in a basic design issue of my project?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean - this is turning into chat. Perhaps we should take it to chat